# Django - Overwriting parent model's Meta

Tags: python, django

I am using the package [django-polymorphic-tree](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic-tree) inside of a Django application.

The `PolymorphicMPTTModel` abstract model from said package has the following Meta:

```
class PolymorphicMPTTModel(MPTTModel, PolymorphicModel, metaclass=PolymorphicMPTTModelBase):
    """
    The base class for all nodes; a mapping of an URL to content (e.g. a HTML page, text file, blog, etc..)
    """

    # ... fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = (
            "tree_id",
            "lft",
        )
        base_manager_name = "objects"
```

Here's a model I wrote that inherits from it:

```
class MyNodeModel(PolymorphicMPTTModel):
    parent = PolymorphicTreeForeignKey(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="children",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # ... fields

    class Meta:
        ordering = (
            "tree_id",
            "-lft",
        )
```

As you can see, I'm trying to overwrite the parent's `Meta.ordering` attribute.

However, if I do this inside of an instance of `MyNodeModel`:

```
print(self.Meta.ordering)
```

it prints:

```
('tree_id', 'lft')
```

which is the parent's value for that field. It appears as though the child class is failing to override that property. Why does this happen?